# iOS UICollectionView Selection

Tags: ios, selection, uicollectionview

My question is simple.  Is it possible to change the gesture for selecting a cell to be a double-tap instead of the default?  If so, what would be the general approach for doing so?

Thanks, in advance.

Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [gesture recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2) to capture gesture events.

I've never seen it done in a main interface; I'd be concerned that Apple will reject it as being noncompliant to the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Both answers are appreciated.  But this one tipped the scales for me; it hadn't occurred to me as an issue but on reading the HIG section related to selection it was clear I needed to make a change to the design.  Thanks again for both replies.